# Creating json array in C# by fetching data from csv

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I want to create the below json using C#. All the data is pulled from a csv file.

```
{
    "car":[
        {
            "manufacturer": "Nissan",
            "fuelType": "petrol",
            "mileage": 20
        },
        {
            "manufacturer": "Nissan",
            "fuelType": "diesel",
            "mileage": 20

        },
        {
            "manufacturer": "Tesla",
            "fuelType": "electric",
            "mileage": 240
        },
        {
            "manufacturer": "Honda",
            "fuelType": "hybrid",
            "mileage": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is the C# code that i have written and also the output that I get when I run the code. I want the car to be an array of objects, instead I am getting an array of with car object containing an array of single car. I am new to C# and json.

```
namespace createJSONfromCSV
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Path = @"C:\Files\CarDetails.csv";
            List<string> csvData = new List<string>();
            List<carDetails> carlist = new List<carDetails>();

            StreamReader reader = null;

            if (File.Exists(Path))
            {
                reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(Path));
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    csvData.Add(line);
                }

                foreach(var item in csvData)
                {
                    if(item != csvData[0])
                    {
                        string[] fields = item.Split(',');
                        carlist.Add(new carDetails()
                        {
                            cars = new List<car>()
                            {
                                new car()
                                {
                                    manufacturer = fields[0],
                                    fuelType = fields[1],
                                    mileage = Convert.ToInt32(fields[2])
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                var carDetailsjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(carlist, Formatting.Indented);
                Console.WriteLine(carDetailsjson);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File does not exist...");
            }
        }
    }
}


class carDetails
    {
        public List<car> cars { get; set; }
    }

    class car
    {
        public string manufacturer {get; set;}
        public string fuelType { get; set; }
        public int mileage { get; set; }
    }
```

The output I am getting is as below:

```
[
    {
      "cars": [
        {
          "manufacturer": "Nissan",
          "fuelType": "Petrol",
          "mileage": 20
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cars": [
        {
          "manufacturer": "Nissan",
          "fuelType": "Diesel",
          "mileage": 60
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cars": [
        {
          "manufacturer": "Tesla",
          "fuelType": "Electric",
          "mileage": 240
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cars": [
        {
          "manufacturer": "Honda",
          "fuelType": "Hybrid",
          "mileage": 100
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Make one list of car. Not a list for every line.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of carDetails object which has only a List property, you should add Car object to the list in foreach condition. So your code should be like;

```
            List<car> carlist = new List<car>();
  carlist.Add(new car()
                                                         {
                                    manufacturer = fields[0],
                                    fuelType = fields[1],
                                    mileage = Convert.ToInt32(fields[2])
                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just build up a single cars list. In the foreach you just add car objects to the list:

```
var cars = new List<car>();

foreach(var item in csvData)
{
     if(item != csvData[0])
     {
           string[] fields = item.Split(',');

           cars.Add(new car()
           {
                manufacturer = fields[0],
                fuelType = fields[1],
                mileage = Convert.ToInt32(fields[2])
           });
     }
}

var carDetailsjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new carDetails() { cars = cars }, Formatting.Indented);
```